# ionic cordova build android / cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1. error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

May be the issue is in gradle. But "gradle -v" command executes on cmd successfully and views gradle version. But I separately downloaded and set path variables to use gradle.

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\intern\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ (DEPRECATED)

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
C:\Users\intern\Desktop\ionic\MyIonicProject\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cordova version >= 7 or Android SDK Tools >= 26 you need to manually install gradle ([reference](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11591)). On Windows 10 you can install gradle like this:

1. Download the binary release from https://gradle.org/releases/
2. Unzip it to any folder you like, for example `C:\gradle`
3. Edit your system environment variables to include the directory `C:\gradle\bin` (where `gradle.bat` is located`)

Afterwards you should be able to build your project normally.

Comment: **Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper.
Please include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio** ---**Error SLOVED**

**--------Below Errors not sloved any one help me---------**

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\raj\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221 (DEPRECATED)

Comment: This is another issue. Please close this one first and follow up with a new question

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Gradle`

there is nice [tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-install-gradle-2.html) for you

this is [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/) site

Comment: **Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper.
Please include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio** ---**Error SLOVED**

**--------Below Errors not sloved any one help me---------**

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Rpwebapps\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Rpwebapps\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined